# pip3 frpm /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, pyenv

`Operation not permitted` when pip install.

I think there is some wrong things on place where pip installed

I'm using pyenv like this

```
➜  test$ pyenv versions
system
3.4.4
3.5.1
3.5.1/envs/analytics
* analytics (set by /Users/username/rec/test/.python-version)
```

and have some pips like this

```
➜  test$ pip3 -V
pip 8.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
➜  test$ pip3.5 -V
pip 8.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I think these things caused `Operation not permitted` error can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried using `sudo`? Normally I don't recommend it but it is useful for overcoming permission errors.

Comment: what os you are using?

Comment: > Tadhg McDonald-Jensen 
Yes, I have tried ang got the `Operation not permitted` error

Comment: Not sure but may be the issue with directory ownership. try to change ownership of the site-packages directory. Don't know much about mac.

Answer (score 0):

You’re still seeing the system-wide pip, even though the `analytics` virtualenv is the active pyenv version.

Most likely you have activated pyenv (in your shell startup), but you’ve forgotten to add `$(pyenv root)/bin` to the front of your `$PATH`.

If in doubt, re-read the [pyenv installation instructions](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/blob/master/README.md), or use [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer) to install pyenv.